# Why would ERROR not be thrown within a Jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to have a mock call throw an error but the I get the error "Expected function to throw error"

Below is the code that I have tried. I have followed a few other things on here but have had 0 luck.

```
it ('should throw err', () => {
    const mockCall = spyOn(service, 'update$').and.returnValue(throwError(new Error(error')));
    expect(mockCall).toThrowError();
});
```

Comment: try to change it to `expect(() => mockCall()).toThrowError()`. What is the reason for testing testing framework API though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a missing single quote `'`. Next, I think you should implement it that way :

```
const mockCall = spyOn(service, 'update$').and.throwError('error');
```

You don't wan't to mock the return of the function, but to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock and throw error from service method using `callFake`. By chaining the `spy` with `and.callFake` , all calls to the spy will delegate to the supplied function :

```
spyOn(service, 'update$').and.callFake(() => throwError(new Error('Fake error')));

expect(service.update$()).toThrow();
```